# What's the default typeface used by JUCE framework

Tags: c++, user-interface, fonts, typeface, juce

What's the default typeface used by JUCE framework GUI?

I need to create SVG with exact same font as used by JUCE GUI by default.

Answer (score 1):

I took one of the `lookAndFeel` methods that return font for parts of UI -

`auto font = juce::LookAndFeel_V4::getAlertWindowFont();`

`font.getDefaultSansSerifFontName()` is an obvious candidate, but it returns only a placeholder - `<Sans-Serif>`.

The actual typeface can be obtained by calling `font.getTypefacePtr()`.

So `font.getTypefacePtr()->getName()` gave me what I've been looking for.
The default typeface, in my case, is `Lucida Grande`.